# Making a slider, can't create viewport

Tags: jquery, css, slider, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make a simple horizontal slider.

As it stands, I have three div's, identical sizes, in a line. I did have jQuery to move them, but currently the viewport moves with them or nothing happens at al.
Can anyone point me in the direction so that the viewport stays fixed and the content slides across it? This is the code so far...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Slider (cutdown, demo)</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#trigger1').click(function(){
$(".box").animate({left: "0"});
});
$('#trigger2').click(function(){
$("#viewport").animate({left: "-200"});
});
$('#trigger3').click(function(){
$(".box").animate({left: "-400"});
});
});
</script>
<style>
body    {
background:#003;
color:#FFF;
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#viewport   {
width:200px;
height:200px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.box    {
background-color:#069;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;
width:196px;
height:196px;
float:left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="trigger1">
Trigger One
</div>
<div id="trigger2">
Trigger Two
</div>
<div id="trigger3">
Trigger Three
</div>
<div id="viewport">
<div id="container">
<div id="box1" class="box">
Box One
</div>
<div id="box2" class="box">
Box Two
</div>
<div id="box3" class="box">
Box Three
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you restructure your trigger menu and rewrite your JQuery code like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="triggerMenu">
    <li id="trigger-0">One</li>
    <li id="trigger-1">Two</li>
    <li id="trigger-2">Three</li>
</ul>

<div id="viewport">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="box1" class="box">Box One</div>
        <div id="box2" class="box">Box Two</div>
        <div id="box3" class="box">Box Three</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**JQuery**

```
$("li", "#triggerMenu").on("click", function()
{
    var triggerNumber = $(this).attr("id").replace(/(.*)-/,"");
    var newPosition = triggerNumber * 200;

    // Make sure the box slides in the right direction
    if (newPosition > 0) newPosition = "-" + newPosition;

    // Slide box
    $(".box").animate({left: newPosition});
});
```

This way you don't have to add new JQuery code for each trigger/box combo.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fAWpZ/5/

Answer (score 1):

Give your .box class a position property. I'd recommend relative. Then give your container a width, say 600px;. Triggers 1 and 3 now seem to work fine.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fAWpZ/2/)**

Comment: Updated http://jsfiddle.net/fAWpZ/3/ - The 2nd button didn't work because you had #viewport instead of .box as the element to animate ;)

Comment: @Tom - Good update. I assumed the OP had that there that way for a reason, but seeing it in action makes way more sense with it as `.box`.

Comment: Tom, j -thanks. This is a cut down version so I didn't have to post reams of code. It should indeed have read `.box` - well spotted.